# Genebank Submission

Tags: phylogenetics

I am not sure this kind of question is allowed here. I am asking because some of you might have already experienced this.

I submitted some virus genomes in the Genebank. The genomes are on hold and are not public yet.My PI thinks thank we should rename the isolates. I have sent two emails to the admin asking that I want to rename the isolates. I sent an Excel file containing accession number, current isolate name and new name that I want to assign. It has been almost a month and I haven't heard back. So, I don't know if this is the right approach.

What should I do now ? Should I just resubmit the genomes ? Or is there any other way to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I usually hear back from the GenBank curators within a single day.

That said, I’d still suggest you wait: it’s unlikely that they missed both of your emails (but maybe double-check the address and whether they’re likely to be caught by a spam filter): they’re probably just swamped with other submissions.

Furthermore, it’s holiday season so they might operate at drastically decreased capacity.